# Why the List is not appending the dictionary data into my list?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have to append the updated dictionary data into list in the below program.

```
hello = ["hello ", "cruel "]
hi = ["hi", "world"]
myli = []
mydict = {}
def abc():
  for i in xrange(len(hello)):
    for j in xrange(len(hi)):
        mydict["Mydata"] = str(j)
        myli.append( [hello[i], hi[j], mydict])

abc()
print myli
```

But the output is coming like 
`[['hello ', 'hi', {'Mydata': '1'}], ['hello ', 'world', {'Mydata': '1'}], ['cruel ', 'hi', {'Mydata': '1'}], ['cruel ', 'world', {'Mydata': '1'}]]`,

where as I am expecting the output like,
`[['hello ', 'hi', {'Mydata': '0'}], ['hello ', 'world', {'Mydata': '1'}], ['cruel ', 'hi', {'Mydata': '0'}], ['cruel ', 'world', {'Mydata': '1'}]]`
I can not understand where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't create a new dict each time but overwrite the value in the one dict `mydict`. Simply create a new dict for each list:

```
def abc(hello, hi):
    myli = []
    for i in xrange(len(hello)):
        for j in xrange(len(hi)):
            myli.append([hello[i], hi[j], {"Mydata": str(j)}])
    return myli

hello = ["hello ", "cruel "]
hi = ["hi", "world"]
print abc(hello, hi)
```

Answer (score 1):

the mydict is update to 1, which means it is replaced by 1 instead of 0, and since you are using the mydict and it directly uses the object.

if you put

```
print myli,mydict
```

at the end of  myli.append( [hello[i], hi[j], mydict]), you will see the result

Answer (score 1):

It's convenient to use a list comprehension for this. Notice there is a new dict
`{"Mydata": str(j)}` created for each item

```
>>> hello = ["hello ", "cruel "]
>>> hi = ["hi", "world"]
>>> [[x, y, {"Mydata": str(j)}] for x in hello for j, y in enumerate(hi)]
[['hello ', 'hi', {'Mydata': '0'}], ['hello ', 'world', {'Mydata': '1'}], ['cruel ', 'hi', {'Mydata': '0'}], ['cruel ', 'world', {'Mydata': '1'}]]
```